# What kind of permission is required to access and rename a directory?

Tags: shell, permissions

Among x, w, r, which permission is required to access and rename a directory. (I'll use cd and mv respectively)

Comment: **r** means read, so correspond to access ,**w** means write, so correspond to modify

Comment: Just note, that for the `mv` you need rights for modify (`w`)the current directory too, because it effectively _writes_ new content (the new name) into it...

Comment: @jm666 could you post your comment as an answer so 장동욱 can mark it as solved?

Comment: @SB87 done, with demo. :)

Comment: Great, now hopefully 장동욱 will mark it as solved :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note, that for the mv you need rights for modify (w)the current directory too, because it effectively writes new content (the new name) into it..

Demo:

```
testdir="./$0.$$"
pwd="$(pwd)"
err()(echo "$@">&2; return 1)

echo "creating $testdir"
mkdir "$testdir" || err "can't mkdir $testdir" || exit 1
ls -la "$testdir"

trap 'cd "$pwd"; chmod 777 "$testdir"; rm -rf "$testdir"; exit' 0 1 2 15

#ensure the 'w' for the demo
chmod 755 "$testdir"

echo "Cd to $testdir"
cd "$testdir" || err "Can't cd to $testdir" || exit 1

echo "mkdir a"
mkdir a || err "Can't mkdir a" || exit 1
ls -la

echo renaming a to b
mv a b || err "can't rename a to b" || exit 1
ls -la

echo "rewoke 'w' permission from the $testdir (now .)"
chmod 555 . || err "can't chmod 555 ." || exit 1
ls -la

echo trying to rename b to c
mv b c || err "can't rename b to c - this failed"
ls -la
```